# How to store model to hdfs using python

Tags: python, hadoop, model, hdfs

I am trying to store my model to hdfs using python.

This code is by using pydoop library

```
import pydoop.hdfs as hdfs

    from_path = prediction_model.fit(orginal_telecom_80p_train[features], orginal_telecom_80p_train["Churn"])
    to_path ='hdfs://192.168.1.101:8020/user/volumata/python_models/churn_model.sav'
    hdfs.put(from_path, to_path)
```

But, while using this, I am getting this error

> AttributeError: 'LogisticRegression' object has no attribute 'startswith'

Then I tried using the pickle option

```
import pickle 
with open('hdfs://192.168.1.101:8020/user/volumata/python_models/') as hdfs_loc:
pickle.dump(prediction_model, hdfs_loc)
```

Pickle option is working fine in local, when i tried to store the model in hdfs, this option is also not working for me. Can anyone please suggest how to proceed further for storing the models to hdfs by using python script?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the full traceback.... Also, not sure where `prediction_model` comes from, but 1) i don't think `prediction_model.fit` is returning a path of a file 2)
   PySpark is commonly used for machine learning with  Hadoop

Comment: you removed the answer?

Comment: Because it doesn't work, yes. I don't use Pickle on Hadoop, so I can't give you a proper solution here

Comment: Then what else you used for hadoop? can give me any other suggestions instead of pickle

Comment: As mentioned, Spark... Which uses Pickle internally

Comment: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-linear-methods.html#logistic-regression

Comment: We cannot store the model in hdfs using plain python without pyspark?

Comment: You **can**... Have you tried using regular `hdfs -put` command? What I posted was **close**, I just don't know how to fix it

Comment: you mean normal hdfs -put using python script?

Comment: I don't, but you could do it that way, sure

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `hdfs.open` instead of `open`, and open the file for writing:

```
import pickle
import pydoop.hdfs as hdfs

with hdfs.open(to_path, 'w') as f:
    pickle.dump(prediction_model, f)
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-5-09aac99ede3d>", line 1, in <module>
    with hdfs.open(to_path, 'w') as f:
  File "/home/volumata/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pydoop/hdfs/__init__.py", line 121, in open
    fs = hdfs(host, port, user)
  File "/home/volumata/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pydoop/hdfs/fs.py", line 146, in __init__
    host = common.encode_host(host)
  File "/home/volumata/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pydoop/hdfs/common.py", line 53, in encode_host
    if isinstance(host, unicode):

Comment: @SARANYA make sure you are using the latest pydoop version, currently 2.0a3: `pip install --upgrade --pre pydoop`. Pydoop 1.x does not support Python 3

Comment: same issue after upgrading also

Comment: Maybe the upgrade wasn't successful. The `if isinstance(host, unicode)` check is not on line 53 in the latest version. Moreover, it's only triggered if you are using Python 2. Check the value of `pydoop.__version__`